# How to find my own iframe's id on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am currently working on some small JavaScript/HTML5 ads for a webpage. Each ad has it's own iframe with a dedicated size/space on the page. For an expandable ad that needs to grow past the predetermined height, I am changing the size of my iframe with this line in my script:

```
parent.document.getElementById('iframe1').style.height = "90px";
```

This works for now, but I am trying to make this future proof as we change our webpage. Is there a way change this without knowing the name of the iframe? Or a way to find the name of my iframe and then change it the way I have been?

Comment: There is not enough information. No, you cannot change the style of something which name you do not know. Yes, you can store your name somewhere in your plugin initialization \ use default names or prefixes etc. However, we can't help with it while we don't see other code.

Comment: I agree with @YeldarKurmangaliyev you need more info its very vague question. Still I tried to answer the question.

Comment: Here you go https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement

Comment: You're right, my question is very vague. I'll make sure I am more clear in the future. (Very new to stack overflow)  But for now, @JaromandaX has found the solution I needed! Now instead of using the iframe's id to change the height, I can use window.frameElement.style.height = "90px". Thanks to all of you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
window.frameElement
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this covers your question but this will log all Iframes on your page.

```
$('iframe').each(function(index,iframe) {
    console.log(iframe);
});
```

Then you could change them all like so.

```
$('iframe').each(function(index,iframe) {
    iframe.style.height = "90px";
});
```

If you want to get the ids.

```
$('iframe').each(function(index,iframe) {
    console.log(iframe.id);
});
```